# how to pass Report Name, parameter & credential to ssrs Report from other webform in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

i am using vs2013 & SSRS Report  2008R2 Advance Express Edition.
i have common reportviewer webform i.e

```
    <form id="CommonReport" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="RV" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="464px" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="661px">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
<div>
</div>
</form>
```

i want pass report name , parameter & sql credential (i.e sql server Name,username & Password) from other webform.

please help , i am  trying since on week.
i did the following code but it asking me username & password , manulay i am typing but i need to pass programitcaly

```
 private void showReport()
    {
        string SSRS = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRS"];
        ReportViewer1.Reset();
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(SSRS); ;// new Uri(urlReportServer); //Set the ReportServer Url
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/sampleReport";
        ReportViewer1.ShowCredentialPrompts = true;
        ReportParameter reptParam = new ReportParameter("proposalId", proposalId.Text);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(reptParam);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: did you find a way to pass the reportservercredentials?

Answer (score 1):

Look into DataSourceCredentialsType by clicking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.datasourcecredentials_members.aspx)

you can add Report DataSource Credential by

```
reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(new[] { new DataSourceCredentials() { Name = "XXX", Password = "XXXXXX" } });
```

Comment: my report  is on ssrs report server so how to pass user name & password.